# In MySQL, how to merge separate columns from two tables?

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to merge the values from TableA and TableB, with bundled_shipping_cost from TableA having priority. TableB's shipping_cost value should only be used when its id does not exist in TableA.

Is there a recommended join statement for this?

**TableA**

### id     |     bundled_shipping_cost   |

```
1      |    100    |      
2      |    200    |      
3      |    300    |      
4      |    400    |
```

**TableB**

### id     |     shipping_cost   |

```
1      |    95     |      
2      |    195    |      
5      |    50     |      
6      |    75     |
```

**TableC**

### id     |     final_shipping_cost   |

```
1      |    100    |      
2      |    200    |    
3      |    300    |  
4      |    400    |    
5      |    50     |      
6      |    75     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need a **kind** of Full Outer Join. Use two different `Select` queries.
- In the first Select query, get all the rows from `TableA`.
- In the second `Select` query, get only those rows from `TableB` which do not
  exist in `TableA` using `Left Join` and `Where TableA.id IS NULL`.
- Eventually [`Union ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) them:

Try:

```
SELECT dt.id, 
       dt.final_shipping_cost 
FROM (
      SELECT t1.id, 
             t1.bundled_shipping_cost AS final_shipping_cost 
      FROM TableA AS t1 

      UNION ALL 

      SELECT t2.id, 
             t2.shipping_cost AS final_shipping_cost  
      FROM TableB AS t2 
      LEFT JOIN TableA AS t1 ON t1.id = t2.id 
      WHERE t1.id IS NULL 
    ) AS dt 
ORDER BY dt.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select q.*from(SELECT *
    FROM `t1`
    union select * from t2) as q group by id
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21104224)